# Attempting to add a foreign key to a table fails?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have two tables -

```
CREATE TABLE `FOO` (
    `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    /*Nothing to see here*/
    PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=380 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `BAR` (
    `ID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `UserID` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
    KEY `VSK_UserID_Index` (`UserID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I am attempting create a foreign key constraint on `BAR.UserID` referencing `users.user_id` -

```
ALTER TABLE `FOO`.`BAR` 
    ADD CONSTRAINT `BAR_UserID_FKey`
    FOREIGN KEY (`UserID`)
    REFERENCES `FOO`.`users` (`user_id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

I keep getting this error -

`Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
Error 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails`

Both of these tables have data in them - could this be the reason why this is happening, or is there something wrong with how the tables are being created?

Is there something I need to alter on one of these tables to make this work?

Comment: If you add a foreign key you have to make sure all data in there is consistant and the relations actually exist

Comment: the one is nullable, the other one ain't

Comment: @juergend I was afraid of that; you're right. I truncated the child table and it worked. *gripe*

Drew - Good catch thanks for that...

Comment: @Drew a nullable column in the child table is not invalid even through the referenced column in the parent table is not nullable. The types, sizes, and signedness have to match, but not nullability.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot , confirmed. Heading him off at the pass, as parent is PK, not null. But yes, strictly speaking, the FK could be created with a mismatch of sorts

Answer (score 1):

The data already in one of the tables (in particular, `` `FOO`.`BAR` ``, since that is the one you're adding a constraint to) is not consistent with the data in `` `FOO`.`users` (`user_id`) ``.

You must ensure that the values un the `` `FOO`.`BAR`.`UserID` `` column all exist in `` `FOO`.`users` (`user_id`) ``. There may be `null` values or other values that do not exist in the other column.